# C++ How to use same class and methods for reading/writing variable size data

Tags: c++, csv

I have written one c++ class which has read and write methods. These methods read and write row from/to csv file.
Currently I have implemented read and write for csv file having five tuples(columns), say - EmpNo, EmpName, Address, Department, Manager.
Class contains these 5 tuples as member variables of class.

So basically, in read(), I am reading row using fstream and putting tuple values in to respective member variable. Similarly, for write I am getting row data from user into class member variable and writing the same in csv file.

Now I want to use same code for reading and writing another csv file having only two tuples out of above five tuples- EmpNo, EmpName.

I can think of maintaining one variable to identify which CSV I am reading/writing and accordingly have if/else in all code. But this doesn't look cleaner approach.
pseudo code for read() with my approach is as below:

```
read()
{
    read EmpNo;
    read EmpName;
    If (csv_with_5_tuple == true)
    {
        read Address;
        read Department;
        read Manager;
    }
}

//Here, 'csv_with_5_tuple ' will be set when reading/writing from/to csv file of five tuples.
```

With this approach, I need to add 'if' condition everywhere in class.

Can anyone suggest me the best way to do this in c++?

Comment: If you *really* must reuse the reading code, use some base class with a virtual method `read_row()` and specialize for the two and five element case.

Comment: How about using something like `std::vector<std::string> row` and `vector<std::string C::*> members` ? so you handle size in constructor directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use class inheritance for this. There are pseudo-code demonstrating the idea:

```
class csv2 {
public:
    virtual void read()
    {
        read EmpNo;
        read EmpName;
    }
};

class csv5 : public csv2
{
public:
    virtual void read()
    {
        csv2::read();

        read Address;
        read Department;
        read Manager;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks Denis, this looks good for read but how about write?
During write I need to write "\n" after writing row in csv file. So lets say my base class 'csv2' write method writes in below way -
    fstreamobj<< EmpNo <<","<< EmpName << "\n";

and derived class 'csv5' write method writes in below way-
    fstreamobj<< Address <<","<<Department <<","<<Manager <<"\n";

This will work for csv2 write but with csv5 it will add two rows in csv file instead of one row.

Comment: You may create protected method `print_impl`, which will print everything except `\n`, and public method `print`, which will call `print_impl` and then output `\n` character. Or, instead, you may create `virtual void print(char term = '\n')` which would do `fstreamobj<< EmpNo <<","<< EmpName << term;`, and from derived class simply call it like `csv2::print(',')`.

Comment: Thanks Denis, this will work for me. just out of curiosity, is there any way to make all this work within same class i.e. without creating any new class.

Comment: Well, in fact there are various ways of doing this. Commenters above already suggested you using `std::vector` of values. You can also take a look at Alexandrescu's templated approach (book "modern c++ programming") or use some variadic macros, but it's quite advanced technique and may be hard to start off.

Answer (score 0):

By using some `vector` and template, you might do:

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> csv_read(std::istream& is, const std::vector<std::string T::*>& members)
{
    std::vector<T> res;
    std::string header;
    std::getline(is, header);
    while (true) {
        T obj;

        for (auto m : members) {
            is >> obj.*m;
        }
        if (!is) {
            break;   
        }
        res.push_back(obj);
    }
    return res;
}
```

With usage similar to

```
const std::vector<std::string Person2::*> members = {&Person2::Name, &Person2::AgeStr};
auto persons = csv_read<Person2>(ss, members);
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/y8ZtG2)

Or simpler if you just use `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> csv_read(std::istream& is, std::size_t rowCount)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> res;
    std::string header;
    std::getline(is, header);
    while (true) {
        std::vector<std::string> row(rowCount);

        for (auto& col : row) {
            is >> col;
        }
        if (!is) {
            break;   
        }
        res.push_back(row);
    }
    return res;
}
```

With usage similar to

```
auto data = csv_read(ss, 2);
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/ikiq79)